# Android : Converting accelerometer output from phone's coordinate into the world coordinate system

Tags: android, accelerometer

I've been working in an Android project that makes use of accelerometer values.

However the output of accelerometer is defined in terms of the phone's coordinate system. but I need them to be in the world's coordinate system ,,

does any body know a method to convert the output values of acceleometer to be in terms of the world's coordinates ?

Regards,

Moustafa

Answer (score 0):

If you mean the x, y, z coordinate, couldn't you just multiply them by -1?
This is what I made when I first started messing around with the accelerometer:

```
package com.semajhan.android.accelerometer;
```

import android.app.Activity;
import android.hardware.Sensor;
import android.hardware.SensorEvent;
import android.hardware.SensorEventListener;
import android.hardware.SensorManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Accelerometer extends Activity {

```
SensorManager sensorManager;
Sensor accelerometer;
TextView textView;
private SensorEventListener sensorEventListener = new SensorEventListener() {

    public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {

    }

    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {

        float x = event.values[0];
        float y = event.values[1];
        float z = event.values[2];
        update(x, y, z);
    }
};
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    textView = new TextView(this);
    setContentView(textView);
    sensorManager = (SensorManager)getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
    accelerometer = sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);
}

public void update(float x, float y, float z) {

    textView.setText("x: " + x + " y: " + y + " z: " + z);
}

protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    sensorManager.registerListener(sensorEventListener, accelerometer, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
}

protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    sensorManager.unregisterListener(sensorEventListener);
}
```

}

Comment: No, I mean that I want to translate the acceleration into the world's coordinate X,Y,Z, so that all the effect of the gravity will be in the Z axis all the time regardless what's the orinetation of the phone

Answer (score 0):

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorEvent.html#values as it says here values - array of accelerations, not coordinates..

Could you cantact me, right now, I'm trying to get phone's coordsinates(not global but local ones) and not sure my stuff's working right.

The idea is that you get phone's world coords on configuring(kinda calibrating) and then apply phone's coordinates into new system